# Multiple UINavigationControllers similar to Maps

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm looking to create a UI similar to that of the Maps application just to try out some odds and ends and brush up on my knowledge of interface builder.

What i'm struggling to discern at the moment is how the Maps application handles the interactions between the toolbar and the navigation controller and which UI elements are needed to mimic the interface. I'm guessing that the Maps app only has one view controller which kind of negates the need for a navigation controller so i'm not sure if i'm using the right application template currently but i'll come back to that one later.

To give you an idea of what I'm looking to copy, if you search for directions between two locations and then hit route, the navigation controller changes from:

> [Clear] Directions [Cancel]
>
> to:
>
> [Edit] {car | train | walk} [Start]

That's all fine so far, nothing out of the ordinary from what i'm used to doing. What is confusing me however is the semi transparent view underneath the navigation controller that displays the total distance and time (or other information depending on the search method). What is the UI element? Is it simply a toolbar tacked on to the main view? How would I go about adding this to my app, is it part of the view, or part of the navigation controller?

Also, in a similar vein... Clicking the `"Search"` segment in the toolbar displays the search field at the top of the app. Is this in the navigation controller, or is the navigation controller hidden whilst the search field is displayed? Again, clicking "Directions" displays the search field but this time with an additional search field and a button to switch the order of the fields. How is this achieved?

I'm not so good with the terminology so excuse me if i've mixed up some terms. I'm just trying to get to grips with the UI elements as i've spent most of my time learning OpenGL so it's all a bit new to me still. If anyone can point out the right UI elements used in the Maps application, that would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks for reading.

Edit: I've [uploaded an image](http://twitpic.com/4hxbed) to illustrate the UI elements i'm querying in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no inside information, so I'm speculating on how I'd do it.

I'd use a UIToolBar for both the top and bottom bars, not a navigation bar. You can put a tool bar anywhere as they're just a subclass of UIView.

The semi transparent view underneath the navigation controller is likely just a custom view on top of the map view. Again, just a subclass of UIView.

The items in both toolbars would call methods in the view controller that could change the contents of either tool bar or hide or show other views.

For example, the Search button might call a showSearchToolbar: method, while the Directions calls a showDirectionsToolBar: method. Both methods would just change the contents of the top tool bar and hide or show the view beneath the top tool bar.

Check out the UICatalog example code from Apple to see how to dynamically change the contents of the tool bar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This seems like a reasonable way to add the elements I require. I'll scope out the UICatalog example and see what I can rustle up. Cheers!